# Ruby: Change negative number to positive number?

Tags: ruby, math, numbers

What's the simplest way of changing a negative number to positive with ruby?

ie. Change "-300" to "300"

Answer (score 307, accepted):

Using `abs` will return the [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of a number

```
-300.abs  # 300
300.abs   # 300
```

Comment: my answer is just for negative numbers, if you need to always have the absolute value then this is definitely the better way.

Answer (score 32):

Put a negative sign in front of it.

```
>> --300
=> 300
>> x = -300
=> -300
>> -x
=> 300
```

Comment: Just note that if the number is already positive, this will make it negative.

Comment: Yeah. Clarified that in my comment to the above accepted answer.

Comment: its either not genius or not not madness.

Comment: why negative votes? this turns negative into positive as OP asked. `#abs` and `-` are different features with same behavior for asked input/output. If that's because of an undesirable `+` -> `-`, it's no more than an assumption, since that was not covered by OP.

Answer (score 20):

Wouldn't it just be easier to multiply it by negative one?

```
x * -1
```

That way you can go back and forth.

Comment: I like using this for clarity, as using the - sign can sometimes be easy to miss

Comment: Worth remembering you can use the shorthand `x *= -1` if you're looking to store the new value...

Comment: Based of the same principle we can even divide the any negative number by -1. However, I was just wondering what can be the benefit of using it over abs method as mentioned by Yacoby

Comment: abs returns an absolute value. If that's all you want, as the OP does, it's fine. But what if you need to go back and forth?

Comment: @ApurvaMayank what's the benefit of using `abs` over this? OP did not mention, but he could either turn positive to negative as well or keep it positive.. you can't assume one without that being mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Most programming languages have the ABS method, however there are some that do not
Whilst I have not used Ruby before, I am familiar its a framework that runs on PHP

The abs method is available on PHP
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php

With Ruby the syntax appears slightly different is integer.abs
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ruby-integer-abs-function-with-example/

But for future reference the abs method is really small to code your self.

here is how in a few different languages:

JavaScript:

```
function my_abs(integer){
    if (integer < 0){
        return integer * -1;
    }
    return interger;
}
```

Python:

```
    def my_abs(integer):
    if (integer < 0):
        return integer * -1
    return integer
```

c:

```
int my_abs(int integer){
    if (interger < 0){
        return integer * -1;
    }
    return integer;
}
```

This means should you ever find yourself with a programming language that doesnt have a built in abs method, you know how to code your own its just simply multiply any negative number by -1 as you would of gathered in my examples

Comment: This doesn't improve on or add to the previous answers (from years ago) as far as answering the original question, which is specifically about ruby.

Comment: In Ruby `abs` and `-` methods are both writen in `C`. One of the main rules for using Ruby: don't try to invent a bicycle, rewriting native `C`-based methods :)
Just click "Show source" to know, how wise people handled that for you)
https://apidock.com/ruby/Integer/abs 
https://apidock.com/ruby/Integer/-

Comment: I feel like this is a good contribution, While not pinpoint specific DataCure is providing greater context as to how different languages address this issue. In fact the last example givin(c) is a great way to quickly flip the value from negative to positive and back. this could easily be written in ruby as: `value * -1`. Thank you DataCure, I feel like this was a good first post.